# GameCenter not refreshing

Tags: xcode, swift, game-center-leaderboard

There is a problem here when I use GameCenter. (By the way, I'm using sandbox mode.)

I update A score on A-device and B score on B-device. I can only see A score on A-device B score on B-device.

I can't always see other people's score, sometimes I can but sometime can't. Is that a GameCenter problem?

If it is the problem of GameCenter itself, Is there any suggestion way for Game leaderboard?

Comment: I had the same problem when I was using it a few weeks ago, Im not sure about my answer so I am only commenting but I believe it is an issue with sandbox mode. I resolved it by adding the two users as friends on Game Center as it forces an update for both users apparently. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Your answer are quite right I thinks. GameCenter did refresh after two or more user update their score. In order to refresh GameCenter, the threshold are likely to be three or four user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bob Gilmore, your answer are quite right I thinks. GameCenter did refresh after two or more user update their score. In order to refresh GameCenter, the threshold are likely to be three or four user.